# Binary Search Tree insertion not working when inserting nodes using while loop

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have posted the link to my BST code on ideone: http://ideone.com/P7850n

In the main function I am getting an error when I read values in the while loop and insert into BST, but it works fine if I use a for loop. What could be the possible explanation for this error which occurs only with the while loop ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//data struct for BST node
typedef struct BST
{
    int data;
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
}node;

//make node from given data
node* makeNode(int data)
{
    node *n=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->data=data;
    n->left=NULL;
    n->right=NULL;

    return n;
}

//insert node in BST
node* insert(node* root,int key)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return makeNode(key);

    if(key < root->data)
        root->left=insert(root->left,key);
    else
        root->right=insert(root->right,key);

    return root;
}

//inorder printing prints in sorted order
void inorder(node* root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return;

    inorder(root->left);
    printf("%d ",root->data);
    inorder(root->right);
}

//driver function
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    node *root;
    int s,i,key;
    scanf("%d",&s);
    while(s--)
    //for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&key);
        root=insert(root,key);
    }
    inorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error..?? Mention the Error.

Comment: What error do you get? In `main()` you must do `node *root = NULL;` ie set `root` to `NULL`.

Comment: First of all initialize your `root` to null. Rest I guess everything is alright. Do as @Rohan has said.

Comment: okay I initialised root to NULL and it works fine but that still doesn't explain why the for loop worked fine but while loop didn't, shouldn't it have raised an error in both cases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `node *root = NULL;` you are trying to access undefined memory address as `root` will contain any random data. So you can get valid behavior or any other behavior including crash.

As `root` is not initialized in `inser()`  function `if(root==NULL)` may or may not be true and hence you will get different behavior.

This has nothing to do with `for` or `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is an uninitialized variable `root`.

The compiler re-uses the same memory for variables, either declared in your program or used internally, after they are not anymore needed, so that other variables later occupy the same memory. In C (unlike, say, Perl), when memory is assigned to a variable, it is not automatically cleared: you should do it yourself, which is called initialization: typically as soon as you declare a variable, you should assign it some value: `int year = 2014;`. If you use a variable before you assign it a value, it's value will be whatever happens to be in memory that it occupies, left from other variables or even other running programs.

In your case, when you initialize the `for` loop with `i=0`, this 0 probably uses the memory later used for `root`, so accidentally it works. When you initialize the `while` loop with non-zero `s`, `root` uses memory that happens to be non-zero.

The solution is to initialize `root = NULL;`, and in general it's a good habit to always initialize all variables.

Answer (score 0):

its always to initialize any memory variable to NULL or any other variable to 0,while writing any piece of code,otherwise you will always get any unpredictable crash or result.
like in this case,do like this below:

node *root;

```
int s,i,key;
```

to

node *root = NULL;

int s =0;

int i = 0;

int key= 0;